# Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html';

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to launch my flutter app, but I encounter the error

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:html'.
```

I have tried to import the `dart.html` with no success.

[image]

Comment: This error is almost certainly caused by depending on web only code in a mobile flutter application.

Comment: Try remove dart.html and run in mobile

Comment: please remove import statement for dart.html and it will be fine

Answer (score 2):

Maybe when you developing, `dart:html` package was imported by mistake. or If you tested app on Web then It could be imported.

If you want test Mobile, Remove that line, It will be work on.

Comment: I removed the line dart:html that was imported by mistake, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. There are mainly two possible solutions I found:

1. If you imported `dart:html`, comment it out.
2. If you do not import `dart:html`, you can try to detect which dependencies in your project depend on `dart:html`. Try commenting them out or implementing alternative dependencies.

My error was caused by `image_picker_for_web`, so I used image_picker instead